# Empty namespaces exported in C++/CLI assembly

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, namespaces

I'm creating a C++/CLI assembly to expose some C++ functions from a native library (pure C++ DLL). The problem is that all namespaces that are declared in the native library headers are exposed in the mixed-mode managed assembly as empty namespaces. Of course, all native headers are included in a `#pragma unmanaged` section.

[Here is an screenshot from the Object Browser after referencing the mixed-mode DLL in a C# project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FU1u4.png)

Only `Asuni.VisualARQ.Script` namespace is not empty. It contains the unique managed class in the entire assembly.

I also understand that `<CppImplementationDetails>` and `<CrtImplementationDetails>` are required because it is a C++/CLI assembly.

How can I get rid of the rest of the namespaces? They are all empty.

Thanks,

Enric